# How to update multiple user's Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm creating a laravel project in which i have multiple users

**what i want to achieve** - I want to update `stime` of selected each user

My Code - which is not working

```
$user = User::where('admin_id','=', $ll);
$user->stime = $request->select;
$save = $user->save();
```

[image: users table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [Update](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#update-statements) method:

this method update existing records it  accepts an array of column and value pairs indicating the columns to be updated. You may constrain the update query using where clauses:

```
User::where('admin_id','=', $ll)->update(['stime'=>$request->select]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update one or more users without fetching them first, use the `update()` method

```
User::where('admin_id', $ll)->update(['stime' => $request->select]);
```

If you want to update just one after fetching it.

```
$user = User::where('admin_id','=', $ll)->firstOrFail();
$user->stime = $request->select;
$save = $user->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$user = User::where('admin_id','=', $ll)->get();
$user->stime = $request->select;
$save = $user->save();
```

I think you are missing ->get on your query.